# JAVA OutOfMemoryError issue With Excel Exporting 150K+ data in the Apache POI Stream API

Tags: java, apache-poi

My Apache POI version is 3.14. I am trying to export large data to excel? To do that I found [this](https://dzone.com/articles/resolve-outofmemoryerror-with-excelexport-export-e) solution on internet and implemented it.

So, I have following List where it came from my Database(PostgresSQL):

`List<TransactionDTO> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.addAll(transactionService.findByInDateRange(status, fromDate, toDate));`

Then I followed the link which I mentioned above (logic exactly the same).

```
   DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd_hh_mm_ss");
    String excelFileName = "Statistics_by_partner" + formatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()) + ".xlsx";
    SXSSFWorkbook wb = (new ExportRevisionResponseExcel()).exportExcel(new String[] { "Status",
        "Request",}, result);
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        wb.write(outByteStream);
        byte[] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.setContentLength(outArray.length);
        response.setHeader("Expires:", "0"); // eliminates browser caching
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + excelFileName);
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        outStream.write(outArray);
        outStream.flush();
        wb.dispose();
        wb.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`
```

However, It is still giving me Memory error.

By the way, I don't think increasing JAVA Heap memory is good idea.

Comment: Why are you buffering the whole file into memory in a byte array then writing? Why not just directly write out?

Comment: This is not my solution. But in my understanding. SXSSFWorkbook stream API we can flush only few(100 exactly) rows of data into memory and the remaining rows can be flushed to the hard memory (permanent memory). For writing permanent memory, I think , buffering is used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely reason that you are running out of heap space is that you are streaming the **entire workbook stream** into a byte array buffer in memory.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    wb.write(outByteStream);
```

This can consume up to three times<sup>1</sup> the actual stream length in bytes.  If you want to use less memory, write the data straight to the response stream:

```
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    wb.write(outStream);
```

Obviously, that means that you won't be able to set a content length in the response.  If that is really important to you, then use a temporary file to buffer the data rather than a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

---

<sup>1 - BAOS uses an internal `byte[]` as the buffer.  When the buffer is full, it allocates a new one of twice the size, and copies data from the old one to the new one.  When you are doing the copying, you have 2 byte arrays, occupying 3 times the number of bytes that have been buffered so far.</sup>